# Saving a subset of a database

Tags: database, sqlite

Here is a complete beginner´s question, maybe someone has time to help: I just downloaded the Corine land cover sqlite file, the whole database has 5.5 GB and takes forever to open. How can I save a geographically defined subset (one country) only, in a new database probably, so that I can actually work with it?

Comment: What software are you using?  Be specific and users will help you on here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ESRI ArcGIS software, use the clip function.  See [THIS VIDEO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UF0l8Ly2U4).  Don't load the data on your map, just clip it from the loation you have it stored at (use the browse folder beside "clip features".

Also, here's a free beginners course with instructions:

[Basic Functions in ArcGIS](http://courses.umass.edu/nrc592g-cschweik/pdfs/Geoprocessing_ArcMap10_Vector_Overlay.pdf)

You can download the data for free off of the ESRI site.  There are a number of [FREE CLASSES](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm) on this webpage as well.  If you're not using ESRI, google "clip" and add the software package you're using to the google search.  You'll find instructions that way.

Hope this helps,
Cheers